# how do I integrate this CTE?

Tags: sql, database, subquery, common-table-expression

the CTE finds the largest invoice 2013, the query after finds the customer name and date of invoice, how do I connect the largest invoice to the customer and the date they invoiced?

```
with highque as (
    select max(ExtendedPrice) highest
    from Sales.InvoiceLines il
    join Sales.Invoices i on il.InvoiceID = i.InvoiceID
    where (InvoiceDate between '1/1/2013' and '12/31/2013')
    group by i.CustomerID
)
select InvoiceDate, CustomerName
from Sales.Invoices i
join Sales.Customers c on c.CustomerID = i.CustomerID
where (InvoiceDate between '1/1/2013' and '12/31/2013')
order by CustomerName
```

sample data:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eaWkC.png)
I just want to connect the highest with the rest of the data

Comment: Sample data and the desired result would help.

Comment: I've updated it with sample data and the desired result is joining the 2 queries

Comment: I couldn't figure out the table format so instead I posted a picture